# PYTHON check if a value in a column Dataset is within a range of values reported in another dataset

Tags: python, sorting, classification

Have read through similar post but can't find an exact solution.
I have a dataset in a column named "A" and want to check if each value in this column is contained within  any of the intervals in another dataset with two column intervals "Start" and "End". Return True or False in column "B" Please see attached image (data always in ascending order). Thank You
[image: data example]

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most efficient solution but it should do what you are asking:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":list(range(20))})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({"START":[1,3,5,7],
                     "END":[2,4,6,8]})


def compare_with_df(x,df):
  for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    if x >= df.loc[row,'START'] and x <= df.loc[row,'END']:
      return True
  return False

df1['B'] = df1['A'].apply(lambda x:compare_with_df(x,df2))
```

As you can see the `compare_with_df()` function loops through `df2` and compares a given `x` to all possible ranges (this can and probably should be optimized for larger datasets). The `apply()` method is equivalent to looping trough the values of the give column (series).

Comment: How would you change the code if the "START" and "END" are in the same column? It would be checking if the value "x" is between "row" and "row+1".

Comment: let me know if this makes sense, if not I will create another example. Thanks again